# making the click event to behave it opposite direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to control the click event which is inside another jquery function. It is working but I want to make it work in opposite direction

here is the code:

```
$(lista).click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#tabbling").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Complete code is like this

```
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    var tabid = $(this).attr("id");
    var listItems = $("#tabbling li");
    var lista = $("#tabbling li a");
    listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    var product = $(li).attr('data-mode');
        if(product == tabid) {
            $(li).addClass('current');
        }else {
            $(li).removeClass('current')
        }
    });
    console.log(listItems);
    $(lista).click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#tabbling").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
});
```

This function behave should be like if I click a link ins the tabs-menu, it should not animate. But it should only animate when I click from the parent menu. If I click from the child tab which is "tabbling", it should just stay there and behave normal without any animation.

Comment: It would **really** help to be able to see you HTML code . . .

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget and https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

Comment: visit this site prolexmedia.ca/home.cfm and click on videography or photography and then going down, if you click any tabs, it just animates